# Magento custome module translation not working

Tags: magento

For a specific module translation is not working for any of it's action. Even if i add the translation in the translate.csv file. And one more thing when i access that module actions then in Chrome translate option is also not showing.

Please help me. I really need help for it. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue. Actually i have override the customer account controller. To resolve the Ddos attach. I override the parent class predispatch function but not calling the parent predispatch from child class.

Answer (score 0):

If the translation file is correct and loaded it most probably comes along with your caching policy. Is the cache emptied ? Do you have varnish or any other similar cache system ? If yes, you need to flush it too.

If things are still not working, please provide more information.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I have solved the issue. Actually i have override the customer account controller. To resolve the Ddos attach. I override the parent class predispatch function but not calling the parent predispatch from child class.